# React - Pass state as props to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to do a conditional render based upon user login. I have a Login component that is being passed the Hook of the username and password through customerLogin and setCustomerLogin:

```
function App() {

    const [customerLogin, setCustomerLogin] = useState([
        { username: "", password: "" }
    ]);

    return(
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/signup' component={Signup}/>                    
                <Route 
                    path='/login' 
                    render={() =>
                        <Login
                            customerLogin={customerLogin}
                            setCustomerLogin={setCustomerLogin}
                        />}
                    />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I would like to do a conditional render based upon whether customerLogin is an empty string versus if a user is logged in and the customerLogin will be set to their username. I have two components SignedInLinks and SignedOutLinks that I would like to use the rendering for in my Navbar component:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="nav-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to='/' className="brand-logo left">Cars4U</Link>
                    <SignedOutLinks />             
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
};

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. The simplest solution I could think of atm is to pass a boolean in your `Navbar` component.

```
<Navbar isLoggedIn={!!customerLogin} />
```

Then on your Navbar component,

```
export const Navbar = ({ isLoggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {isLoggedIn ? <SignedInLinks /> : <SignedOutLinks />}
    </div>
  )
}
```